# Why is the "enter or Select a database" dropdown list blank in the "Add Connection" wizard for visual web developer?

Tags: database-connection, sql-server-2005-express

Why is the "Select or enter a database name" drop down list blank when I try to add a connection to my SQL Server Express edition using visual web developer 2008, using the "Add Connction" wizard and type "Sql Server".  I can type a name in if I know what the database is that I'm looking for, but that list is blank.  I've seen this over and over, and I've also seen it work okay, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried enabling all the connection protocols in SQL Server Configuration Manager, but it didn't help.  I've seen this on at least two different workstations, so I'm not sure if it's some setting I've made in both, or if this is known bug?  I don't see a whole lot of people with this issue on in my searching. this post seems to be similar, but the answers didn't address the blankness.
[ASP.NET: connecting to a sql server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327920/asp-net-connecting-to-a-sql-server-database)
I really don't have trouble connecting, it's just annoying not to see the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list will be filled if your Server Name is filled out and correct.  You also typically should specify the instance in the format

Server\Instance

(local)\SQLEXPRESS 
or
.\SQLEXPRESS

I've never seen the list filled by default.

Comment: I used SQLEXPRESS as an example value, your instance name could be different.

Comment: When I added it, I selected the server name from the "Server Name" drop down list. That defaults to my HOSTNAME\SQLEXPRESS in this case.  I assumed that would mean the server name was correct,since the test connection works at that point.However, after your post, I switched to it localhost\SQLEXPRESS, then hit refresh, and that did it.   I then switched it back to HOSTNAME, and refreshed again, and the database name list was still populated.  Still kind of mystery to me why it wouldn't take right away with the HOSTNAME, but at least I know how to kickstart it, in a sense.  Thanks for the help!